# Redirecting do a page and alert pop up

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I have created an html form for registering and when a user has successfully registered I want them to be automatically redirected back to my `index.html` page and for an alert to pop up tell them they have Registered Successfully. Currently my alert works but it just opens up in a blank page. I have tried putting in  `header ("location:../index.html")` but that has not worked, it just directs me straight to the page without giving me the alert i want. Can anyone help with this?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db("mayan",$con);
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
     $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
     $lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
     $address=$_POST['address'];
     $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
     $emailaddress=$_POST['emailaddress'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $query = "select emailaddress FROM mayan_users where emailaddress='$emailaddress'";
     $link = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
     $num = mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($num>0){
  echo 'Email already exists'; //email already taken
 }

 else {
 $insert_query = "insert into `mayan_users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`postcode`,`emailaddress`,`password`) values('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$postcode','$emailaddress','$password')";
 $result = mysql_query($insert_query)or die(mysql_error());



  if(success)
{
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('success');".
        "</script>";
}
     }

   }
?>
```

Comment: if(success) -> is this a function or a variable, if this is a variable, it should be $success. And when is this one set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function when redirecting:

```
function redirect($url) {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    } else {
        //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
        exit;
    }
}
```

So you want to redirect to the same page but with a ?=XXX Get value

Your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['success'] == 1){
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('success');".
        "</script>";
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db("mayan",$con);
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
     $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
     $lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
     $address=$_POST['address'];
     $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
     $emailaddress=$_POST['emailaddress'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $query = "select emailaddress FROM mayan_users where emailaddress='$emailaddress'";
     $link = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
     $num = mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($num>0){
  echo 'Email already exists'; //email already taken
 }

 else {
 $insert_query = "insert into `mayan_users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`postcode`,`emailaddress`,`password`) values('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$postcode','$emailaddress','$password')";
 $result = mysql_query($insert_query)or die(mysql_error());



  if(success)
{
   redirect('index.php?sucess=1');
}
     }

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to redirect someone back to the homepage after filling in a form on a website.

```
if(empty($errors))
{
    //send the email

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("YOUR MESSAGE"); 
            window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";</script>';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect by JavaScript use:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

But I would suggest adding a link for the user to click on as well as some users might have JavaScript disabled. And I'd put a timeout on the redirection, so the user has a few seconds to read the page. E.g.:

```
if (success) {
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . 
         "setTimeOut(function() {" . 
         "   window.location = 'http://www.google.com';" . 
          "}, 2500);" .
         "</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a variable in the index page like "index.php?success". Then just check for this request by if(isset($_GET['success']). And add some login to that IF.

Answer (score -1):

1) First of all change your **index.html** into a php file: **index.php**

2) On the top of the **index.php** file write

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

3) In the body of the **index.php** file you can:

either print a message

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
     echo $_SESSION['message'];
     unset($_SESSION['message']);
   }
?>
```

or alert with javascript

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
     echo '<script> alert(\'Success\'); </script>';
     unset($_SESSION['message']);
   }
?>
```

4) On this action file you gave us

```
<?php

  // START THE SESSION
  session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db("mayan",$con);
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
     $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
     $lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
     $address=$_POST['address'];
     $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
     $emailaddress=$_POST['emailaddress'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $query = "select emailaddress FROM mayan_users where emailaddress='$emailaddress'";
     $link = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
     $num = mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($num>0){
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Email already exists'; //email already taken
 }

 else {
 $insert_query = "insert into `mayan_users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`postcode`,`emailaddress`,`password`) values('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$postcode','$emailaddress','$password')";
 $result = mysql_query($insert_query)or die(mysql_error());



  if($result)
  {
     $_SESSION['message'] = 'Success';
  }
 }

}
// redirect to main page
header("Location: /");
?>
```